# How to configure ELResolver without using JSF

Tags: jsp, el

In my project, I override some functions extends `javax.el.ELResolver` (version 3.0). And I put the Class in the configuration file in JSF `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>com.myapp.common.el.SectionELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Now, I want to remove the JSF framework, but to keep configuration of my `ELResolver`. How to configure? 
What can I do to write a servlet and how to be configured in `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do it programmatically via [`JspApplicationContext#addELResolver()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.html#addELResolver-javax.el.ELResolver-). There's no `web.xml` support for this. You can use  a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to perform the task.

```
@WebListener
public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        JspFactory.getDefaultFactory()
                  .getJspApplicationContext(event.getServletContext())
                  .addELResolver(new SectionELResolver());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```